# Window.Open Issue in Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

When running the following script in Microsoft Edge, we are getting unexpected behavior.

```
var specs = "width=" + screen.width + ", height=" + screen.height + ", fullscreen=yes";
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", specs);
```

The first time it runs, it will open a window in fullscreen. However, if we resize that fullscreen pop-up window to be smaller, close the pop up, and try to execute the script a second time, it will NOT pop up as fullscreen. Instead it opens to the size of the resized original popup.

How do we force the pop up to always respect the last parameter set in `windows.open`?

Comment: I am actually not able to replicate the problem - can you post an example?

Comment: Sure. First, go to this link, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open3. Then, replace the content in myFunction() function with the one provided in the original post. Click on the "See Results" on the top right of the left pane to reflect the changes. On the right pane, click on the "Try it" button. The result you will get is a full pop up window for the first time, and adjust (reduce) the size of the pop up window manually, then close the pop up. Click on the "Try it" again. Now, instead of popping up the full window, it will pop up the window with the reduced size

Comment: Ill check it out shortly - as a general fyi, its awesome to have urls that don't require additional steps. I made http://jsbin.com/bequgixiro/ for this. Its a free site, and _super_ useful for scratchpad coding.

Comment: Hi Patrick, any update on that?

Comment: I am still not able to replicate it using Edge. Can you try my version of the demo to see if you are able to have it happen to you? https://output.jsbin.com/huqufo

Comment: I am seeing the same issue.  Edge seems to be ignoring my window.open values when I try to popup from iframed content.

Comment: Patrick, your example is working.

Comment: If you want to replicate the error, pls see the bootbox exmaple page: http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html. Click on the Alert button. the popup just flash and disappear.